# Responsividade usando React e Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, react, layout-responsivo

Estou com um problema que já venho tentando solucionar a um bom tempo, e não consigo, que é deixar o layout do site pegando a pagina toda, ele fica desse jeito. https://ibb.co/cHEeS7 (print de como está)

Repare que ele ocupa apenas 70% da tela, o código está assim.

```js
//login.js
class Login extends Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" id="container-login">
                <div>
                <h2 className="mb-5">Form subscription</h2>
                    <form>
                        <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Subscribe</p>
                        <Input label="Your name" icon="user" group type="email" validate error="wrong" success="right"/>
                        <Input label="Your email" icon="envelope" group type="email" validate error="wrong" success="right"/>
                        <div className="text-center">
                            <Button color="deep-orange" color="indigo">Send</Button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
 </div>
```

```css
html{
 border:black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;

}
body{
  border:rgb(92, 252, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
#root{  
  border: gold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-image: url("./img/download.jpg");
}
#div-app{
  border: royalblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

#div-main{
  border: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;

}

#container-login{
border:rgb(147, 9, 160);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;

}
```

Coloquei borda em cada div para tentar explicar melhor o meu problema,

Unica maneira que consegui fazer funcionar foi setando um ( height: 100%; ) em todos desdo HTML até #container-login, isso fez com que pegasse 100% da tela,.

Segue imagem https://ibb.co/kOMLZn

Pensei que o problema taria resolvido, porem quando coloco a resolução simulando um celular junto com mais formulários e botões a tela estoura para baixo e as div não vem junto.

segue imagem https://ibb.co/fa7mqS

Nesse exemplo aqui https://ibb.co/jEvgqS consigo deixar mais claro oque acontece.

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar a tela toda, você precisa usar a "container-fluid" ai ele vai pegar 100% da tela. Diferente do "container" que deixa encaixotado o layout.

Espero ter ajudado.

Mais infos na documentação do bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Comment: Dê uma elaborada na resposta, como sugestão, adicione um exemplo e transcreva o que o link.